# Where to find Phone.dll file for getting Call Logs (PhoneOpenCallLog)?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I can't find Phone.dll file on my computer and getting Can't find PInvoke DLL 'Phone.dll'.

Where will I find Phone.dll file?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a DLL that you "find".  It is shipped on the device, baked into the ROM.  It would be in the |Windows folder, and most likely a hidden file, meaning that you probably can't see it using the on-device explorer, though the Remote File Viewer will show it.

If a p/invoke call is not finding it, however, it's likely that it's not there.  What type of device, specifically, are you targeting?  Obviously not all WinMo devices are phone devices, so if it's not a phone device the DLL won't be present.  I don't believe it's present in the emulator either.

Comment: I am testing this on Emulators. I am able to get it working on WM 6.5 & 6.1 Professional but not on WM 5 or 6. Do you know why?

Comment: Anybody knows from where can I download phone emulators to test Call Log sample?